# Regex filter with parsely.js failing if I exceed a certain number of patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, parsley.js

Apologies for any etiquette mistakes; as many times as I've searched SO, I've never posted.

I'm using a regex string with parsely.js in a form. When it looks like this, it works:

```
^(?:(?!8005952062)|(?!800-595-2062).)*$
```

When it looks like this, it doesn't:

```
^(?:(?!1234567890)|(?!123-456-7890)|(?!5555555555)|(?!555-555-5555)|(?!8667442540)|(?!866-744-2540)|(?!8665943187)|(?!866-594-3187).)*$
```

Am I missing something obvious, or is there a limit to the number of patterns that can be passed to regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like this:

```
^(?:(?!1234567890|123-456-7890|5555555555|555-555-5555|8667442540|866-744-2540|8665943187|866-594-3187).)*$
```

Using the examples above only proved invalid on the last item while allowing all the others through.

Example: [JSFiddle parsley.js example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zpqwj/1/)

Comment: Thanks, Bryan! Testing now.

Edit: That was it! Perfect.